# paeseInt vs Implicit return the same result but second failing in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

what is the difference between these two codes? they result in the same but the jest not passing for implicit return

```
// version one:

function reverseInt(n) {
  const reverseInt = n.toString().split("").reverse().join("");
  return parseInt(reverseInt) * Math.sign(n);
}

//version two 

function reverseInt(n) {
  const reverseInt = n.toString().split("").reverse().join("");
  return reverseInt * Math.sign(n);
}
```

the jest are below, let me know if need anything to discover more about this issue. i want to know the reason why thanks for your time!!

```
const reverseInt = require('./index');

test('ReverseInt function exists', () => {
  expect(reverseInt).toBeDefined();
});

test('ReverseInt handles 0 as an input', () => {
  expect(reverseInt(0)).toEqual(0);
});

test('ReverseInt flips a positive number', () => {
  expect(reverseInt(5)).toEqual(5);
  expect(reverseInt(15)).toEqual(51);
  expect(reverseInt(90)).toEqual(9);
  expect(reverseInt(2359)).toEqual(9532);
});

test('ReverseInt flips a negative number', () => {
  expect(reverseInt(-5)).toEqual(-5);
  expect(reverseInt(-15)).toEqual(-51);
  expect(reverseInt(-90)).toEqual(-9);
  expect(reverseInt(-2359)).toEqual(-9532);
});
```

Comment: Can you share the jest test where you see this behavior?

Comment: Consider not having a local variable be the same as the name of the function?

Comment: In the second version you are returning a `string` value. As you did `n.toString()`, your overall value stored in **reverseInt** is string. And In the jest, you are expecting an Integer output.

Comment: but typeof reverseInt*Math.sign(n); should be Number as I check in my node env

Comment: Reversing the digits of a negative number will result in the minus being last `-123` will become `321-`. This will cause the multiplication to result in `NaN`.